# What is the difference between allocating array like int a[10][10] and allocating array using new keyword in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

I am presently using Windows 10 with **gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)**.
Code 1

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int** a = new int*[100000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        a[i] = new int[1000];
    cout << "Array allocation Ok!!!\n";
    return 0;
}

//Output
Array allocation Ok!!!
```

Code 2

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arr[100000][1000];
    cout << "Array allocation Ok!!!\n";
    return 0;
}

//I got no Output, it just return the console back to me
```

Someone suggested me the difference could be that in Code 2 row **i** and **i+1** are contiguous (row major representation) i.e. `int arr[1000][100]` is same as `int arr[100000]` in terms of memory. But in Code 1 the column entries are contiguous in nature but not the rows. But if that could be the case then what about **pointer arithmetics**?

Comment: what you mean by pointer arithmetics?

Comment: The second program crashes due to stack overflow. The other differences are not relevant to your problem. You will see the same output if you use a smaller array, say `int arr[10][10];`.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a duplicate with regard to the link.  The OP was asking about memory alignment of heap allocations versus stack allocations, not stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that a[10][10] is allocated on the stack and the array being allocated with new is allocated on the heap.